# adding barButtonItems to a UINavigationBar without a Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am attempting to add a number of buttons to a uiNavigationBar, but it is not attached to a navigation controller, and I don't want it to be.

I am attempting to add two buttons to the left side of the bar, but the only examples of code I find that allow this involve using the line

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems
```

obviously, my UINavigationBar is not a navigatinItem.

Here is how I have created my NavBar..

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationBar *navBar;
```

.m

```
_navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
[_navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,52)];
[self.view addSubview:_navBar];
```

I have seen two ways to push items to a nav bar but neither work.

first being..

```
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                  target:self
                                  action:@selector(buttonSettingClicked)];

    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:barButton]
```

and

```
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = _ArrayOfBarButtons;
```

neither one produces any results... i suspect because my UINavigationBar is not technically a 'navigation item.'

So how can I add items to my NavigationBar?

Comment: You can start by reading the "Adding Content to a Navigation Bar" section of the UINavigationBar Class reference. As it says, you need to add your buttons to an instance of a UINavigationItem. In your code, you reference self.navigationItem, but you never create one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the UINavigationItem first, add the button to it, and then add the navigationItem to the navigation bar.

```
[super viewDidLoad];
    _navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
    [_navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,52)];
    [self.view addSubview:_navBar];
    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc]initWithTitle:@""];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(buttonSettingClicked)];
    [navItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButton];

    [_navBar setItems:@[navItem]];
```

Comment: Oh, ok, so its as simple as then then...  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JesseDurham, yep, it is. If you want multiple buttons, just create more of them, use setLeftBarButtonItems:, and pass an array of your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
  m_navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
  [m_navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,52)];
  [self.view addSubview:m_navBar];

  UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(buttonSettingClicked)];


  UINavigationItem* navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyItem"];
  [m_navBar pushNavigationItem:navItem animated:NO];

  navItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[barButton, barButton];
```